# SqLite: Cursor does not increment correctly

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I am having an issue where my cursor's respective while loop is not running. Cursor.columncount() returns the appropriate amount of columns. Are there any errors in how I increment my cursor?

A Pictoral View (Column returned):

```
|Rating|
|2     |
|3     |
|6     |
```

Function should return 11/3 (3.66666)

```
public double getAverageRating(String title) {
        title = title.toUpperCase();
        int rating = 0;
        int count = 1;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String str = "SELECT RATING FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE TITLE=" + "'" + title + "'" + ";";
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(str, null);
        while(cur.moveToNext()) {
            int b = Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("RATING")));
            rating += b;
            count++;
        }
        cur.close();
        return (double) rating/count;
        //return rating;
    }
```

Comment: When you single-step through the code in your IDE debugger, what happens?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio, so it's a little confusing. Basically, there are no runtime errors.Through other testing, I found that  the while loop is never accessed. I tested my query in SqliteBrowser, and it works correctly.

Comment: The tutorial I found shows a `moveToFirst()` followed by a `do { ... } while(moveToNext())`.  Have you tried this?

Comment: @JimGarrison That is just a gratuitously more complex way of doing the same thing.

Comment: The obvious answer is that there are not rows with that title in the DB.